# Accessing attributes of a WPF application from another thread in main application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I started a WPF application on a thread of my main application.

Now I want to access a text box in this WPF application from the main thread.

I was trying to use dispatchers but I could not figure out a way.

Here is my code

```
  class program
{
    public static event MyEventHandler event1;
    static Application a;
    static void fun()
    {
        a = new Application();
        a.StartupUri = new Uri("MainWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
        //a.initializeComponent();
        a.Run();

    }

     //[STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fun));
        newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        newThread.Start();
        Trace.WriteLine("rest");
        //I WANT TO ACCESS THE TEXT BOX FROM HERE 


    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to access an attribute? What attribute are you trying to access? There isn't enough information to see what you have tried to make this work.

Comment: @MartinNoreke I tried to elaborate. Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1. the main thread needs a reference to the window and/or textbox

   - Have the thread that creates the window/textbox put a reference to the window/textbox in a static variable
2. When the main thread wants to access the textbox it has to switch to the thread that created the textbox and get the result from that thread.

   - Only the thread that created a control can safely access that control. See this question [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

From an answer on that question:

```
string x;
TheTextBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => x = TheTextBox.Text));
```

Comment: would be thankful if you could elaborate on point one. I already have a reference to Application i.e. a . But I cannot get a reference to my current WPF application (how do I get that?). Without it,  I cannot reference "TheTextBox" here.

Comment: What do you mean by the current application? The code only contains a single application and you can get it by using App.Current

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to do something like this to loop the active windows of the application to find the window you need, then call a method on that window to get the actual text box element you need.

```
    public void AccessTextBox(string windowName, string textBoxName)
    {
        foreach (Window windowToCheck in a.Windows)
        {
            if (!windowToCheck.Name.Equals(windowName, textBoxName))
                continue;
            windowToCheck.Dispatcher.Invoke(((WindowTypeName)windowToCheck).AccessTextBox(textBoxName));
        }
    }
```

The Dispatcher.Invoke call is a call that puts you on the UI thread, executes a call the the specified method, and returns to your current thread.

This is psuedo-code (quite ugly too :) ), but should put you on the right path.